Gatsby-source-contentful proxy settings
How can I set the body length and content length in the gatsby-source-contentful plugin.
'maxContentLength': Infinity, 'maxBodyLength': Infinity
Plugin configuration in gatsby-config.js file
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: `your_space_id`,
        // Learn about environment variables: https://gatsby.dev/env-vars
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
  ],
}

I tried setting maxContentLength and maxBodyLength as proxy inside options. Getting an error as invalid plugin options.
